# Why subscription not firing after first subscribe for a hot observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

in my code I created a hot observable with share() and if I don't complete the observable , or use setTimeout make it async, only the first subscription is executed, any additional subscription after it won't execute at all. Is this an expected behaviour?

```
const c=Rx.Observable.create((obs)=>{
obs.next(1)
// add this will work
// setTimeout(()=>obs.next(1),1000)
// add this will work too
// obs.complete()
}).share()

// excuted
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('first subscribe'))
// not excuted
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('second subscribe'))
```

and if I instead use publish connect approach it works as expected.

```
const c=Rx.Observable.create((obs)=>{
obs.next(1)
}).publish()

// excuted
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('first subscribe'))
// excuted
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('second subscribe'))
c.connect()
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/4071)

Comment: The observable you've created emits `1` synchronously and then does nothing. So, by the time the second subscriber has subscribed, your observable has already emitted `1` to the shared subscription and the second subscriber therefore receives no notifications. If your observable were to emit `1` asynchronously, both subscribers would receive it.

Comment: You created a **hot** observable. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: @cartant so you think it is an expected behaviour? but it kinda defeat the documentation specification, created a bit confusion, since it's converted to hot already.  I think same situation encountered when working with sync operation like Observable.from([ array]).merge(...). Maybe rx should add some docs about sync execution cases.

Comment: @a better oliver , it should emit to both subscription if it's hot

Comment: Yes. It is absolutely the expected behaviour. You might want to read: https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339

Comment: if i complete the observable by obs.complete() both subscription fire, here's the confusion bit. I also tried the publish() and connect() it works, just edited my question

Comment: @cartant thanks for the link. Think i read it before, in this case I think it's a design decision related questions. Since observable is capable of both sync and async.

Comment: Both snippets exhibit the expected behaviour. You need to look closely at them with regard to when the subscription to the source is made from the shared or published observable because that's where your confusion lies.

Comment: I understand why it executed like this, correct me if i am wrong. it's a matter of whether .next() is is executed in a callback eventloop (async) or just inside create - the main thread (sync).

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the example step by step.

```
Rx.Observable.create((obs)=>{
  obs.next(1)
})
```

This creates an observable and the function you pass to `create` is executed when a subscription is requested.

```
.share()
```

This shares the upstream subscription. That means that the first subscriber makes `share` create a subscription to the source and all following subscribers share (sic!) this subscription. If all subscribers cancel their subscription the subscription to the source is cancelled as well. Note that a new subscription is also created when the stream has completed before.

```
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('first subscribe'))
```

The first subscriber subscribes, the `share` operator creates a shared subscription. Hence the subscription function is executed and a value is emitted.

```
c.subscribe(()=>console.log('second subscribe'))
```

The second subscriber subscribes and the `share` operator re-uses the already existing subscription to the source. Therefore the subscription function is **not** executed and no value is emitted.

If you add `.unsubscribe()` to the first `subscribe` then it would work as you expect it, because the shared subscription is cancelled and the second subscriber leads to another execution of the subscription function.

Comment: Thanks for the taking time to answer. Please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g5pj065m/4071/, if you change obs.next to setTImeout(()=>obs.next('k')) the share() operator doesn't behave the same.

Comment: @FanCheung Of course it does. You still have one execution of the subscription function, but because of `setTimeout` the value is emitted **after** the second `subscribe`.

Comment: yes it is more related to whether is a sync or async operation. I know it is rare that we excute an sync operation in create(). I think rx doc should  give some warning about this. Most of the article that I saw doesn't explain this. The impression i get is share() publish() turn cold to hot but not mention sync or async. Same thing happen for Observable.from(array).merge(Observable.from(array))

Comment: @FanCheung I agree that it can be confusing and your example would be even harder to understand if we didn't know the definition of the stream `c`. Conclusion: It's important to know the characteristics of the stream you subscribe to.